# Stored procedure not functioning

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Iam trying to make a stored procedure that calculates business points on a ranking system of gold,silver platinum and so on.I made this procedure but it gives my error and not able to figure out what the issue is.It says check mysql syntax on the queries ,but when i run the queries separately they run fine.Can any one help me figure out what the issue is am i doing something wrong.IAm new to procedures.This was supposed to be done from front end but now it is supposed to be done from backend the database.
Please help and advise

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE procedure weightedavg(IN  businessid INT(11))
 BEGIN
 SET @basic = 1;
 SET @silver = 2;
 SET @gold = 4;
 SET @platinum = 8;
 SET @diamond = 16;

 select @badgegold:=@badgegold user_badge_id from user_badge_masters where        
 user_badge_desc="Gold";
 select @badgePlatinum:=@badgePlatinum user_badge_id from user_badge_masters where      
 user_badge_desc="Platinum";
 select @badgeSilver:=@badgeSilver user_badge_id from user_badge_masters where    
 user_badge_desc="Silver";
 select @badgeDiamond:=@badgeDiamond user_badge_id from user_badge_masters where     
 user_badge_desc="Diamond";
 select @badgeBasic:=@badgeBasic user_badge_id from user_badge_masters where    
 user_badge_desc="Basic";



  SET @sum_valg= select SUM(review_trans.rating_given) as sum
        from `review_trans` where  `review_trans`.`business_id`=businessid  and      
  `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`=@badgegold
        GROUP BY `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`;




  SET @sum_valp= select SUM(review_trans.rating_given) as sum
        from `review_trans` where  `review_trans`.`business_id`=businessid  and    
  `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`=@badgePlatinum
        GROUP BY `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`;

        SET @sum_vals= select SUM(review_trans.rating_given) as sum
        from `review_trans` where  `review_trans`.`business_id`=businessid  and 
  `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`=@badgeSilver
        GROUP BY `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`;

       SET @sum_vald= select SUM(review_trans.rating_given) as sum
        from `review_trans` where  `review_trans`.`business_id`=businessid  and 
   `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`=@badgeDiamond
        GROUP BY `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`;

       SET @sum_valb= select SUM(review_trans.rating_given) as sum
        from `review_trans` where  `review_trans`.`business_id`=businessid  and 
    `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`=@badgeBasic
        GROUP BY `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`;


        SET @sum_valg_count=select count(user_id) from review_trans where   
   user_badge_id=1;  
         SET @sum_vals_count=select count(user_id) from review_trans where 
   user_badge_id=4;  
          SET @sum_valp_count=select count(user_id) from review_trans where 
   user_badge_id=3;  
           SET @sum_valb_count=select count(user_id) from review_trans where 
   user_badge_id=6;  
            SET @sum_vald_count=select count(user_id) from review_trans where 
   user_badge_id=5;





        IF @sum_valg=0 THEN
        set @gold_avg=0
        else
        set @gold_avg=@sum_valg/@sum_valg_count;


          IF @sum_valp=0 THEN
        set @platinum_avg=0
        else
        set @platinum_avg=@sum_valp/@sum_valp_count;



          IF @sum_vals=0 THEN
        set @silver_avg=0
        else
        set @silver_avg=@sum_vals/@sum_vals_count;

        IF @sum_vald=0 THEN
        set @diamond_avg=0
        else
        set @diamond_avg=@sum_vald/@sum_vald_count;

        IF @sum_valb=0 THEN
        set @basic_avg=0
        else
        set @basic_avg=@sum_valb/@sum_valb_count;


        IF @gold_avg <=0 THEN
        set @gold_effectiveweight=0
        else
        set @gold_effectiveweight=@basic;

        IF @platinum_avg <=0 THEN
        set @platinum_effectiveweight=0
        else
        set @platinum_effectiveweight=@platinum;


         IF @silver_avg <=0 THEN
        set @silver_effectiveweight=0
        else
        set @silver_effectiveweight=@silver;


         IF @diamond_avg <=0 THEN
        set @diamond_effectiveweight=0
        else
        set @diamond_effectiveweight=@diamond;


        IF @basic_avg <=0 THEN
        set @basic_effectiveweight=0
        else
        set @basic_effectiveweight=@basic;


        set @total_weight=@gold_effectiveweight+@platinum_effectiveweight+
        @silver_effectiveweight+@diamond_effectiveweight+@basic_effectiveweight;

     set @basic_weighted_score=@basic_effectiveweight/@total_weight;
     set @silver_weighted_score=@silver_effectiveweight/@total_weight;
     set @gold_weighted_score=@gold_effectiveweight/@total_weight;
     set @plat_weighted_score=@platinum_effectiveweight/@total_weight;
     set @diam_weighted_score=@diamond_effectiveweight/@total_weight;


      set @avg_basic_weighted_score=@basic_weighted_score*@basic_avg;
      set @avg_silver_weighted_score=@silver_weighted_score*@silver_avg;
      set @avg_gold_weighted_score=@gold_weighted_score*@gold_avg;
      set @avg_plat_weighted_score=@plat_weighted_score*@platinum_avg;
      set @avg_diam_weighted_score=@diam_weighted_score*@diamond_avg;

          @business_point=@avg_basic_weighted_score+ @avg_silver_weighted_score+
      @avg_gold_weighted_score+@avg_plat_weighted_score+@avg_diam_weighted_score;

          @business_point=TRUNCATE(@business_point,1);
          UPDATE businessmasters SET business_point=@business_point WHERE    
          business_id=businessid;


  END;//
     Delimiter ;
```

Comment: First thing I would recommend: use local variables instead of user defined ones. Do comment your code, for yourself, for others too. Lastly: what error message do you get?

Comment: it said check syntax for "SET @sum_valg= select SUM(review_trans.rating_given) as sum
        from `review_trans` where  `review_trans`.`business_id`=businessid  and      
  `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`=@badgegold
        GROUP BY `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`;" query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your SELECT statements in parenthesis to work.
So instead of

```
SET @sum_valg= select SUM(review_trans.rating_given) as sum
        from `review_trans` where  `review_trans`.`business_id`=businessid  and      
  `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`=@badgegold
        GROUP BY `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`;
```

you should use

```
SET @sum_valg=(select SUM(review_trans.rating_given) as sum
        from `review_trans` where  `review_trans`.`business_id`=businessid  and      
  `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`=@badgegold
        GROUP BY `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`);
```

then it should work.
You have to do that with all your SET statements where you want to assign values calculated by a query.